# Using retrofit2 and Okhttp to GET Api

Tags: android, api, get, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to use GET method to show my product data in layout. i can upload product using POST method it work fine but using GET not working
here is my code for ApiService Interface

I am getting this error from the l

Java

```
        public interface ApiService {

          @Multipart
          @POST("/se/product")
            /* @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")*/
          Call<Product> saveProduct(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> file, @Part("name") RequestBody name, @Part("price") RequestBody price, @Part("quantity") RequestBody quantity, @Part("idCategory") RequestBody idCategory,
                                    @Part("model") RequestBody model, @Header("Authorization") String token);

              @GET("/se/product/{productId}")
              Call<Product> getProduct(@Body RequestBody id,@Header("Authorization") String token);
            // @GET("/se/product/{productId}")
            //  public void getProductDetails(@Part("product_id") String product_id, Callback<Product> callback);
            }
```

and this is my class for product

```
  public class ProductsDetails extends AppCompatActivity {
                    ApiService chuckService;
                    TextView price,quantity,model,name;
                    ImageView file;
                    String token;
                    @Override
                    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_details);
                        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
                        model = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.model);
                        price = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.price);
                        quantity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity);
                        file = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.file);


                        ApiService chuckService = Okhttp_RetrofitClient.getClient().create(ApiService.class);




                        JSONObject paramObject = new JSONObject();

                        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf((paramObject)));
                            Call<Product> call = chuckService.getProduct(body,token);
                            call.enqueue(new Callback<Product>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Call<Product> call,
                                                       Response<Product> response) {
                                    name.setText(response.body().getName());
                                    price.setText(response.body().getPrice());
                                    quantity.setText(response.body().getQuantity());
                                    model.setText(response.body().getModel());
                                    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(response.body().getFile()).
                                            into(file);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(Call<Product> call, Throwable
                                        t) {
                                    name.setText(t.getMessage());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
```

here is my POJO for product

```
  public class Product {
                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return "Product{" +
                                "id=" + id +
                                ", quantity=" + quantity +
                                ", idCategory=" + idCategory +
                                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                                ", model='" + model + '\'' +
                                ", published=" + published +
                                ", price=" + price +

                                '}';
                    }

                    private String productId;

                    public String getProductId() {
                        return productId;
                    }

                    public void setProductId(String productId) {
                        this.productId = productId;
                    }

                    public List<String> getImages() {
                        return images;
                    }

                    public void setImages(List<String> images) {
                        this.images = images;
                    }

                    private List<String> images = null;
                    public Integer getId() {
                        return id;
                    }

                    public void setId(Integer id) {
                        this.id = id;
                    }

                    private Integer id;
                    @SerializedName("quantity")
                    @Expose
                    private  String quantity;


                    @SerializedName("idCategory")
                    @Expose
                    private    Integer idCategory;


                    public String getQuantity() {
                        return quantity;
                    }

                    @SerializedName("name")
                    @Expose
                    private  String name;


                    @SerializedName("model")
                    @Expose
                    private  String model;



                    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
                        this.quantity = quantity;
                    }

                    public Integer getIdCategory() {
                        return idCategory;
                    }

                    public void setIdCategory(Integer idCategory) {
                        this.idCategory = idCategory;
                    }

                    public String getName() {
                        return name;
                    }

                    public void setName(String name) {
                        this.name = name;
                    }

                    public String getModel() {
                        return model;
                    }

                    public void setModel(String model) {
                        this.model = model;
                    }

                    public boolean isPublished() {
                        return published;
                    }

                    public void setPublished(boolean published) {
                        this.published = published;
                    }

                    public Integer getPrice() {
                        return price;
                    }

                    public void setPrice(Integer price) {
                        this.price = price;
                    }

                    public String getFile() {
                        return file;
                    }

                    public void setFile(String file) {
                        this.file = file;
                    }
                    @SerializedName("published")
                    @Expose
                    private  boolean published;


                    @SerializedName("price")
                    @Expose
                    private Integer price;


                    @SerializedName("file")
                    @Expose
                    private String file;

                }
```

here is the xml to see the product details

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/detail_product"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_margin="16dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="375dp"
                        android:layout_height="409dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:text="Nom du produit"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="20sp"
                            android:textStyle="italic" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_margin="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/file"
                                android:layout_width="50dp"
                                android:layout_height="202dp"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/model"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:text="Details"
                                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="12sp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/price"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:text="Cfa. 190.000"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="20sp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/price"
                                android:text="Quantite"
                                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Stacktrace

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body. for method 
ApiService.getProduct at 
retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755) at com.monsokoseller.app.Activities.ProductsDetails.onCreate(ProductsDetails.java:50)
```

Comment: I am getting this error from the logcat                                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Non-body HTTP method cannot contain @Body.
        for method ApiService.getProduct
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:755)

        at com.monsokoseller.app.Activities.ProductsDetails.onCreate(ProductsDetails.java:50)

Comment: should you not use post instead of get?

Comment: @Raghunandan i am trying to see the product information after published, POST method is not working.

Answer (score 0):

GET requests cannot contain Request-Bodies. The api cannot contain a GET-Request with a request body. Please check the api docs again.

You can try the API with [curl](https://curl.haxx.se). What exactly you want to supply in the body? If you just need to supply the `productId`, the interface declaration can be changed to:

```
@GET("/se/product/{productId}")
          Call<Product> getProduct(@Path("productId") productId,@Header("Authorization") String token);
```

This call replaces the variable `{productId}` in the request path with the actual product id.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but could u show me an example?